# PHP give active class to active item in navigation

Tags: php, navigation

I'm trying to give the active nav item a .active class using php but i don't know any solution to make this happen. At the moment its always number 1 active even if its not. I don't really see the problem so i was hoping you guys might can help me out.
This is what i have at the moment:

```
<?php
$pages = $db->queryarray("
        SELECT p.name, 
               u.url 
        FROM pages p
            , url u 
        WHERE p.active=1 
            AND p.hidden=0 
            AND p.root=0 
            AND p.menu=1 
            AND u.type='s' 
            AND u.source=p.id 
        ORDER BY p.position ASC
    ");

$i=1;

foreach($pages as $page)
{
    echo '<li>
                <a title="Pagename"'.($i==1?' class="active"':"").'href="index.php#page_'.str_replace(' ','_',strtolower($page['name'])).'">'.$page['name'].'</a>
          </li>';
    $i++;
}
?>
```

@mhakvoort

```
echo '<li><a title="Pagename" class="'.($page['active']) ? "active" : "" .'" href="index.php#page_'.str_replace(' ','_',strtolower($page['name'])).'">'.$page['name'].'</a></li>';
```

Comment: what is the result of `print_r($pages);`?

Comment: The first will always be active, because you set $i to be 1, and if $i == 1 the page will be active.

Comment: The result of the print is: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name
            [url] => /Name.html
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => About Us
            [url] => /about-us.html
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => The product
            [url] => /the-product.html
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Contact
            [url] => /contact.html
        )

)

Comment: @marijn do you want only php solution?

Comment: @jamershwart lopez doesnt have to be but i would prefer PHP

Comment: @marijn did my answer helped you out?

Comment: @MHakvoort im checking it out now trying to put it in my code that proper way, i'll let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an identifier which page is the current page therefore we can take advantage of `$_GET` php variable.

Please note i have change `index.php#page_` to `index.php?page=`

```
foreach ($pages as $page) {
         $pageIdentifier = str_replace(' ','_',strtolower($page['name']));

         $findActivePage = isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] ==  $pageIdentifier? " class='active' ": "";

         echo '<li><a title="Pagename" '.$findActivePage.' href="index.php?page='.$pageIdentifier.'">'.$page['name'].'</a></li>';

    }
```

---

You can also use jquery for adding active class when your anchor tag is click.Note I have added a **`menu_item`** class to your anchor tag.

```
foreach ($pages as $page) {
         $pageIdentifier = str_replace(' ','_',strtolower($page['name']));
         echo '<li><a  class="menu_item" id="page_'.$pageIdentifier.'" title="Pagename" href="index.php#page_'.$pageIdentifier.'">'.$page['name'].'</a></li>';

    }
```

Jquery code

```
 //menu item click event.

    $("a.menu_item").on("click",function(){
        //Remove active class in all a.menu_item
        $("a.menu_item").removeClass("active");

        //Add active class to the clicked menu_item
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: downvoter please coment. Explain why my answer needs to be downvoted.

Comment: You're solution is getting me pretty close but there is one issue, i need the index.php?page=  to be index.php#page_ because the other scripts im using, after changing is back its not working. I'll try to figure it out now but so far its pretty usefull

Comment: Thats the reason why ask if you need php only solution.I will update my answer later, Because I think a bit of javascript is needed.

Comment: i'm sorry about that didn't really understand the question but i appreciate your help

Comment: @marijn I have update my answer please check. Hope that helps you :D

Comment: at this point the menu in not working when you press the buttons the active class is not showing up and the menu is not scrolling to the ankerpoint. I'll try to figure out whats wrong. Thanks for the help so far i really appreciate it

Comment: i checked console its given Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined gonna check that out now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101650/discussion-between-jameshwart-lopez-and-marijn).

Comment: make sure you have include jquery in your project.

Comment: its working now thanks to jameshwart thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The first will always be true because of your if statement `$i == 1;`

To add the class active to your active page you would need something like this, depending on your field names.:

In your query you need to add the active boolean, and check on it in the a tag:

```
<?php
$pages = $db->queryarray("
        SELECT p.name,
               p.active, 
               u.url 
        FROM pages p
            , url u 
        WHERE p.active=1 
            AND p.hidden=0 
            AND p.root=0 
            AND p.menu=1 
            AND u.type='s' 
            AND u.source=p.id 
        ORDER BY p.position ASC
    ");

$i=1;

foreach($pages as $page)
{
    echo '<li>
                <a title="Pagename"'.($page['active']) ? 'class="active"' : "").'href="index.php#page_'.str_replace(' ','_',strtolower($page['name'])).'">'.$page['name'].'</a>
          </li>';
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Like this i'm getting the result activeactiveactiveactive in my navbar i'll try to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Can you show the code the way you edited it? I added your exact code with the edited parts merged.

Comment: got it like this now, code is also in a codeblock above echo '<li><a title="Pagename" class="'.($page['active']) ? "active" : "" .'" href="index.php#page_'.str_replace(' ','_',strtolower($page['name'])).'">'.$page['name'].'</a></li>';

Comment: the link will always be actived since the WHERE is `p.active=1 ` which is the results  `$page['active']` and will always be `1`

Comment: used your last edit @mhakvoort and it gives me a blank page and no errors in the console.

Comment: I've seen in your code that all the menu-items are active, so actually my code is useless I guess.